# how to get sessionAttribute to the userprofile after login

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

                String firstname = request.getParameter("USERNAME");
                 String Password = request.getParameter("PASSWORD");

            try {

              if (firstname != null )
              {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample", "root", "");
                  String Query ="SELECT * FROM  user WHERE username=? AND password=?";
                  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
                  ps.setString(1, firstname);
          ps.setString(2, Password);

                  ResultSet as = ps.executeQuery();
                  if (as.next()) 
                  {

here my sessionAttribute? I try here to get the user to the index user profile but i coudn't so far?




                       request.setAttribute("username", firstname);
                       HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                       session.setAttribute("username",firstname);
                       System.out.println("Welcome"+firstname+""+session.getId());
                       RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
                       rd.forward(request, response);
                     /*  response.sendRedirect();*/
```

here my connection to sql?

```
                  }
                  else {
                      response.sendRedirect("login falied try again please!! ");

                  }
              }

            }
                 catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException  | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException  | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block;
        out.println("Exception : "+e.getMessage());
                     }
            }
}
                   @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
@Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

}
```

}

Why doesn't this work? I have tried Googling and found using absolute pathways (which I'm trying to avoid for now) and using "//", which doesn't work either.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The jsp already has access to the session object.
No need for

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
```

Just use

```
session.setAttribute("username",firstname);
```